# rails3 authlogic-connect unknown attribute: oauth_provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm trying to use the authlogic-connect plugin to add oauth support to my web app but I'm getting the error:

```
unknown attribute: oauth_provider
```

when UsersController#create is called. It is failing when I try to create a new user from the parameters that are being passed in:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

Sure enough, the parameters include this attribute:

```
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "authenticity_token"=>"lHX2BTFTd5xITTfY/X8A9R3vca3YaRuHFoWdqy8ZPik=",
 "user"=>{"oauth_provider"=>"linkedin"},
 "commit"=>"LinkIn"}
```

From the documentation, I assumed that this was what you are supposed to do:

```
Second, if you are using Oauth, you must include an input with name oauth_provider 
and value twitter or whatever other provider you might want (see example apps for 
dynamic example).
```

Any ideas on how this is supposed to work? All of the example forms are in yaml - which I don't know - and I'm trying to create this from using embedded ruby code. Here's the form that I'm using:

```
<!-- authlogic-connect hack -->
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<%= f.radio_button(:oauth_provider, "linkedin") %>
<%= f.label(:oauth_provider_linkedin, "Link In Fool") %>
<%= f.submit :value => "LinkIn" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: As suggestion: move to devise + omniauth, you can install it within just one hour. It will be full featured authentication. Look for screencasts or asciicasts.

Comment: Ha! That's exactly what I did this morning and I could not agree more that the answer to this question is devise + omniauth :) Authlogic simply does not have rails3 support and it's not worth the effort to try to make it work when devise + omniauth is so easy to get running.

Answer (score 0):

As Dimitry pointed out, the best answer to this question is to use devise + omniauth instead of trying to get authlogic to work. Authlogic simply doesn't support rails3. I spent at least a week trying to get authlogic to work the way I wanted and I never solved the problem. I then spent a few hours getting devise + omniauth to do exactly what I want (i.e. you can create an account with LinkedIn or on the sight and you can associate them together so that you can login with LinkedIn or with email and password to the same account).